# Нарушение прав доступа при записи

Tags: c++, исключения

Сначала распишу что у меня есть ( свой недовектор ( специально убрал все методы, чтобы осталось как можно меньше кода  и, структурка TNodе ):

## TNode.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
struct TNode {
public:
    uint32_t Key;
    uint64_t Value;
};
```

## TVector.h

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

#define DLAB1_TVECTOR_START_CAPACITY 10

template <class Type>
class TVector {

private:
    Type *Data;
    uint64_t Size;
    uint64_t Capacity;

public:
    TVector( void ) {

        Capacity = DLAB1_TVECTOR_START_CAPACITY;
        Size = 0;
        Data = ( Type* ) malloc( sizeof( Type ) * Capacity );


    }

    TVector( uint64_t size ) {

        Capacity = size;
        Size = 0;
        Data = ( Type* ) malloc( sizeof( Type ) * Capacity );

    }

    ~TVector( void ) {

        free(Data);

    }

    Type& operator [] ( uint64_t id ) {

        return Data[ id ];

    }

};
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TNode.h"
#include "TVector.h"

#define DLAB1_TEST_MEMB_AMMOUNT 100000000

int main() {
    try {
        TVector<TNode> vector( DLAB1_TEST_MEMB_AMMOUNT );

        for ( uint64_t i = 0; i < DLAB1_TEST_MEMB_AMMOUNT; i ++ ) {
            TNode newNode = { i, i };
            vector[i] = newNode;
        }
    } catch(std::bad_alloc) {
        std::cerr << "Bad alloc!\n" << std::endl;
    }  


    return 0;

}
```

## Внимание вопрос

Если я ставлю тест на, например 40,000,000 - всё в порядке. Как только я перехожу этот предел, получаю следующее -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужен тест на 100 миллионов. В мейн специально трай запихнул, это не нехватка памяти точно ( к тому же там всего полтора гига на это должно уйти )

Comment: На самом деле это есть нехватка памяти. Вы не проверяете, что вам вернула функция malloc, а вернула она вам NULL указатель. Функция malloc - это C функция. Она не выбрасывает исключения.

Comment: Если вы ловите `bad_alloc`, то вам стоило бы пользоваться `new`, который его бросает. `malloc` не бросает ничего, это сишная функция.

Comment: Размер `TNode` с учётом padding'а будет 128 байт. `128 * 40000000 = 5120000000 = 4.8Gb`, вполне достаточно для переполнения адресного пространства.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд это именно нехватка памяти. То есть система неспособна выделить такой экстент памяти.

Функция malloc - это C- функция. Она не выбрасывает исключения. Поэтому данный try-catch блок

```
try {
    TVector<TNode> vector( DLAB1_TEST_MEMB_AMMOUNT );

    for ( uint64_t i = 0; i < DLAB1_TEST_MEMB_AMMOUNT; i ++ ) {
        TNode newNode = { i, i };
        vector[i] = newNode;
    }
} catch(std::bad_alloc) {
    std::cerr << "Bad alloc!\n" << std::endl;
}
```

не имеет большого смысла.

Если работа функции `malloc` была безуспешной, то она возвращает NULL указатель, что она вам и вернула в конструкторе.

Вы не проверяете в конструкторе был ли успешным вызов `malloc`.

```
TVector( uint64_t size ) {

    Capacity = size;
    Size = 0;
    Data = ( Type* ) malloc( sizeof( Type ) * Capacity );

}
```

В результате, так как `malloc` вернула NULL указатель, в цикле, где вы инициализируете элементы, произошло обращение к нулевому адресу и, соответственно, возникло необработанное исключение.